# Trying to get my H1 centered.... JSFiddle included

Tags: html, css, web

I have been trying to rack my brain as to why I can't seem to apply any attributes to my H1 tag... I couldn't get it to work and started trying to put a border around it so I could see where the section was actually at. But I couldn't even get the border to appear on the section. At first thinking that maybe you couldn't put a border round a section because it was possibly more of a metaphorical grouping and not an actual "physical" grouping... I then tried putting it within a div tag and an article tag, to which I still had no success...

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <section id="under_banner"></section>
    <section id="main_pic"></section>
    <section id="title">
            <h1>The Adventures of Chris Wakeling!</h1>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS is...

```
/* Basic Underlay */ 
html {
background-color: #03113D;
z-index: -2;
}
#under_banner {
border-radius: 5px;
background-image: url("images/sydney.jpg");
background-position: 0px -180px;
background-size: cover;
margin: 0px auto;
height: 350px;
width: 1100px;
z-index: -1;
}   

/* Main Body */
#main_pic {
background-color: #000;
width: 550px;
height: 600px;
}
h1 {
text-align: center;
width: 550px;
height: 600px;
margin: auto;
border: 1px solid #999;
background-color: white;
}
```

Basically if you open up the code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QuenchingTurtle/gF5rb/), in the result there is supposed to be an empty space due to a picture. but I want the "Adventures of Chris Wakeling" to be centered.

Any help would be appreciated...

Cheers in advance.

Comment: `#under_banner {` no close

Comment: Hey apologies, there is a close curly in the code, just missed it in the Copy and paste.

Comment: wow.... voted down... apparently there is such thing as a silly question... my bad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this css style

```
#title h1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

it will make your h1 come to the center.

Add a closing brace `}` to `#under_banner`

Comment: Hey mate sorry about that, I didn't realise I missed it in the copy and paste. it is in the code still..

Comment: My apologies.... again.... lol you were right I checked the wrong section in CSS ^_^

Answer (score 0):

the title is centered in relation to body but `<section id="under_banner"></section>` = `width: 1100px;` is larger than the body is not.

*you can put `body {width: 1100px;}` and greatest `#title` will be centered*

```
   <body>
            <section id="under_banner"></section>
            <section id="main_pic"></section>
            <h1 id="title">The Adventures of Chris Wakeling!</h1>
    </body>
```

css

```
/* Basic Underlay */ 
body {
    background-color: #03113D;  
    }
#under_banner {
    border-radius: 5px;
    //background-image: url("images/sydney.jpg");
    background-color: red;
    background-position: 0px -180px;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 350px;
    width: 1100px;
    z-index: -1;
}
#main_pic {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 550px;
    height: 600px;
    }
#title {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    width: 550px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background-color: #000;
    }
```

Comment: Ok but how does that effect it. I've tried adjusting #main_pic #title to match 1100px which is not wider than my body. and that doesn't seem to help, I am still not getting the text to align. if I float #under_banner to the left then the text goes to the right. so its still relative to the #under banner. so why can't it be aligned to the center underneath that picture?

Comment: with relation to size in a shorter screen you will not work : `<section id="under_banner"></section> = width: 1100px;`

Comment: you can use `position:absolute;` in `<section id="under_banner"></section>`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here for some layout modifications.  I think this is what you are likely looking to achieve.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gF5rb/4/)

```
<body>
<section id="under_banner">Under Banner</section>
<div id="wrapper">
    <section id="main_pic">Main Picture Section</section>
    <section id="title">
        <article>
                <h1>The Adventures of Chris Wakeling!</h1>

        </article>
    </section>
</div>
```

The problem is, unless you give a frame of reference such as a width to center to, it keeps the block only as big as it is needed.  Adding a wrapper around elements that need to stay contained (I notice your banner was expected wide) can help you keep a reference to revert to.